# Some components aren't responsive to events

Tags: java, swing, events, focus

My `Event Controller` class isn't receiving events from the `JColorChooser` whenever its chosen color changes, nor is it receiving `KeyEvents` from the `JComponent` (The one I'm using to draw the star into). I've checked thoroughly and just couldn't find the issue, here's my code (I've omitted package and imports for convenience):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GestorDeEventos ge=new GestorDeEventos();

    Interfaz f=new Interfaz();

    ge.setVentana(f);
    f.setGestorEventos(ge);
}
}

public class Interfaz extends JFrame {

private GestorDeEventos miGestor;

private Container c;

AreaDeDibujos lienzo;

private JLabel lInfo,lCantidadPuntas,lTamanioEstrella,lLargoPuntas,lColor,lRotar;
JSpinner spinnerCantidadPuntas;
JSlider sliderTamanioEstrella;
DoubleJSlider sliderLargoPuntas;
JColorChooser ccColor;
JButton bRotarIzquierda,bRotarDerecha;
public Interfaz(){

    setTitle("Ejemplo <<Dibujo de primitivas y poligonos>> Version 1.1 (07/02/2013)");
    setSize(1024,720);
    setResizable(false);

    c=getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(new Color(240,250,245));
    c.setLayout(null);

    lienzo=new AreaDeDibujos(600,600);
    lienzo.setLocation(400,15);

    c.add(lienzo);

    // Para informar al usuario del proposito de dicha seccion de la interfaz
    lInfo=new JLabel("Por favor, seleccione los parametros de la estrella a dibujar:");
    lInfo.setBounds(10,10,350,20);
    c.add(lInfo);

    // Para seleccionar la cantidad de puntas de la estrella
    lCantidadPuntas=new JLabel("Numero de puntas de la estrella: ");
    lCantidadPuntas.setBounds(10,35,350,20);
    c.add(lCantidadPuntas);
    spinnerCantidadPuntas=new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(7, //valor inicial
                                                              Estrella.MINIMO_PUNTAS, //valor minimo
                                                              Estrella.MAXIMO_PUNTAS, //valor maximo
                                                              1 // incremento/decremento (paso)
                                                             )
                                       );
    spinnerCantidadPuntas.setBounds(10,55,120,20);
    /*
      En la siguiente linea deshabilito el campo de texto del JSPinner de modo que su valor
      solo pueda ser editado mediante los botones que incluye el propio JSpinner, esto lo hago
      para evitar que alguien coloque un valor fuera del rango [Estrella.MINIMO_PUNTAS, Estrella.MAXIMO_PUNTAS]
    */
    ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinnerCantidadPuntas.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
    c.add(spinnerCantidadPuntas);

    //Para seleccionar el tamaño de la estrella
    lTamanioEstrella=new JLabel("Tamaño de la estrella (pixeles): ");
    lTamanioEstrella.setBounds(10,80,350,20);
    c.add(lTamanioEstrella);
    sliderTamanioEstrella=new JSlider( 
                                     JSlider.HORIZONTAL,
                                     AreaDeDibujos.TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MINIMO,
                                     AreaDeDibujos.TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MAXIMO,
                                     (int)(AreaDeDibujos.TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MAXIMO/2)
                                     );
    Hashtable etiquetasDelSlider1 = new Hashtable();
    int i,cantidadDeRayas,rango,paso,minimo,maximo,valorDeLaRaya;
    minimo=AreaDeDibujos.TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MINIMO;
    maximo=AreaDeDibujos.TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MAXIMO;
    rango=maximo-minimo;
    cantidadDeRayas=10;
    paso=rango/cantidadDeRayas;
    for(i=0;i<=cantidadDeRayas;i++){
        valorDeLaRaya=minimo+paso*i;
        etiquetasDelSlider1.put(new Integer (valorDeLaRaya), new JLabel(""+valorDeLaRaya));
    }
    sliderTamanioEstrella.setLabelTable( etiquetasDelSlider1 );
    sliderTamanioEstrella.setPaintLabels(true);
    sliderTamanioEstrella.setMajorTickSpacing(paso);
    sliderTamanioEstrella.setPaintTicks(true);
    sliderTamanioEstrella.setBounds(10,100,350,60);
    c.add(sliderTamanioEstrella);

    //Para seleccionar el largo de las puntas de la estrella (% con respecto al tamaño total de la estrella)
    lLargoPuntas= new JLabel("Largo de las puntas(%): ");
    lLargoPuntas.setToolTipText("(% con respecto al tamaño total de la estrella)");
    lLargoPuntas.setBounds(10,165,350,20);
    c.add(lLargoPuntas);

    sliderLargoPuntas=new DoubleJSlider(100, 900, 367, 1000);
    Hashtable etiquetasDelSlider2 = new Hashtable();
    minimo=100;
    maximo=900;
    rango=maximo-minimo;
    cantidadDeRayas=10;
    paso=rango/cantidadDeRayas;
    for(i=0;i<=cantidadDeRayas;i++){
        valorDeLaRaya=minimo+paso*i;
        etiquetasDelSlider2.put(new Integer (valorDeLaRaya), new JLabel(""+valorDeLaRaya/10));
    }
    sliderLargoPuntas.setLabelTable( etiquetasDelSlider2 );
    sliderLargoPuntas.setPaintLabels(true);
    sliderLargoPuntas.setMajorTickSpacing(paso);
    sliderLargoPuntas.setPaintTicks(true);
    sliderLargoPuntas.setBounds(10,185,350,60);
    c.add(sliderLargoPuntas);

    // Para seleccionar el color
    lColor=new JLabel("Color: ");
    lColor.setBounds(10,250,350,20);
    c.add(lColor);
    ccColor=new JColorChooser(new Color(0,255,255));
    ccColor.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());
    JScrollPane spColor=new JScrollPane(ccColor);
    spColor.setBounds(10,270,350,250);
    c.add(spColor);

    //Para rotar la estrella
    lRotar=new JLabel("Rotar: ");
    lRotar.setBounds(10,525,350,20);
    c.add(lRotar);

    bRotarIzquierda=new JButton("<");
    bRotarIzquierda.setBounds(63,545,80,40);
    c.add(bRotarIzquierda);

    bRotarDerecha=new JButton(">");
    bRotarDerecha.setBounds(206,545,80,40);
    c.add(bRotarDerecha);

    setFocusable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void setGestorEventos(GestorDeEventos ge){
    miGestor=ge;
    spinnerCantidadPuntas.addChangeListener(miGestor);
    sliderLargoPuntas.addChangeListener(miGestor);
    sliderTamanioEstrella.addChangeListener(miGestor);
    ccColor.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(miGestor);

    bRotarDerecha.addActionListener(miGestor);
    bRotarIzquierda.addActionListener(miGestor);

    lienzo.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    /*addKeyListener(miGestor);
    spinnerCantidadPuntas.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    sliderLargoPuntas.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    sliderTamanioEstrella.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    ccColor.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    bRotarDerecha.addKeyListener(miGestor);
    bRotarIzquierda.addKeyListener(miGestor);*/
}

}

public class AreaDeDibujos extends JComponent {

public static final int TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MINIMO=50,TAMANIO_ESTRELLA_MAXIMO=400;
private DibujoDeEstrella dibujo;

public AreaDeDibujos(int largo, int ancho){
    setFocusable(true);
    setSize(largo,ancho);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    if(dibujo!=null){
        g.setColor(dibujo.getColor());
        for(Polygon d: dibujo.getDibujos())
            g.fillPolygon(d);
    }        
}

public void pintarEstrella(DibujoDeEstrella d){
    dibujo=d;
    repaint();
}
}

public class GestorDeEventos implements ChangeListener,KeyListener,ActionListener {

Interfaz ventana;
AreaDeDibujos areaDeTrabajo;

DibujoDeEstrella dibujo;

public GestorDeEventos() {
}

public void setVentana(Interfaz ventana) {
    this.ventana = ventana;
    areaDeTrabajo= ventana.lienzo;
    dibujo=new DibujoDeEstrella(
                               new Estrella(
                                           ventana.sliderTamanioEstrella.getValue(),
                                           (int)ventana.spinnerCantidadPuntas.getValue(),
                                           ventana.sliderLargoPuntas.getScaledValue(),
                                           ventana.ccColor.getColor()
                                           )
                               );
    areaDeTrabajo.pintarEstrella(dibujo);
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==ventana.sliderLargoPuntas){
        dibujo.setLargoDePuntas(ventana.sliderLargoPuntas.getScaledValue());
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==ventana.sliderTamanioEstrella){
        dibujo.setTamanio(ventana.sliderTamanioEstrella.getValue());

    }
    else if(e.getSource()==ventana.spinnerCantidadPuntas){
        dibujo.setCantidadPuntas((int)ventana.spinnerCantidadPuntas.getValue());

    }
    else if(e.getSource()==ventana.ccColor){
        dibujo.setColor(ventana.ccColor.getColor());
    }
    areaDeTrabajo.pintarEstrella(dibujo);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { //NO USADA, AL NO DECLARAR NADA ADENTRO ESTAMOS EFECTIVAMENTE
                                   //IGNORANDO TODOS LOS EVENTOS DE ESTE TIPO
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dibujo.moverIzquierda();
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dibujo.moverDerecha();
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dibujo.moverArriba();
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dibujo.moverAbajo();
    }
    areaDeTrabajo.pintarEstrella(dibujo);
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { //NO USADA, AL NO DECLARAR NADA ADENTRO ESTAMOS EFECTIVAMENTE
                                      //IGNORANDO TODOS LOS EVENTOS DE ESTE TIPO
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(ventana.bRotarIzquierda)){
        dibujo.rotar(-1);
    }
    else if(e.getSource().equals(ventana.bRotarDerecha)){
        dibujo.rotar(1);
    }
    areaDeTrabajo.pintarEstrella(dibujo);
}

}

public class DibujoDeEstrella {

private Estrella miEstrella; //Aqui guardamos los datos de la estrella como tal (independiente de como la dibujaremos)

private LinkedList<Polygon> dibujos; //Esto es lo que entregaremos al JComponent para que dibuje la estrella

/* Las siguientes variables sirven para generar el dibujo a partir de la estrella, en ellas
   contemplamos parametros como lo son el angulo actual de la estrella, la posicion actual dentro
   del JComponent, y los puntos de los 2 circulos que usamos para construir el dibujo, todas usadas
   para crear los poligonos LISTOS PARA SER DIBUJADOS
*/
private int posicionActualX,posicionActualY;
private double anguloActual,circuloInteriorX[],circuloInteriorY[],circuloExteriorX[],
               circuloExteriorY[],radioDelCirculoInterior,radioDelCirculoExterior,
               gradosEntreCadaPunto,anguloEntrePuntos,anguloInicial,desplazamiento;
public DibujoDeEstrella(Estrella e){
    miEstrella=e;
    posicionActualX=0;
    posicionActualY=0;
    anguloActual=0.0;
}

private void crearDibujo(){
    calcularCirculos();
    int i;
    dibujos=new LinkedList<Polygon>(); //El centro + cada una de las puntas
    //creamos el centro de una sola vez y lo introducimos dentro de la lista de poligonos a dibujar
    dibujos.add(crearCentro());
    Polygon punta;
    for(i=0;i<circuloExteriorX.length;i++){
        punta=new Polygon();
        punta.addPoint((int)circuloInteriorX[i], (int)circuloInteriorY[i]);
        punta.addPoint((int)circuloExteriorX[i], (int)circuloExteriorY[i]);
        if(i+1<circuloExteriorX.length)
            punta.addPoint((int)circuloInteriorX[i+1], (int)circuloInteriorY[i+1]);
        else
            punta.addPoint((int)circuloInteriorX[0], (int)circuloInteriorY[0]);
        dibujos.add(punta);
    }
}

private Polygon crearCentro(){
    int cx[],cy[],cantidadDePuntos;
    cantidadDePuntos=miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas();
    cx=new int[cantidadDePuntos];
    cy=new int[cantidadDePuntos];
    int i=0;
    for(double x: circuloInteriorX)
        cx[i++]=(int)x;
    i=0;
    for(double y: circuloInteriorY)
        cy[i++]=(int)y;
    return new Polygon(cx,cy,cantidadDePuntos);
}

private void inicializarVariables(){
    //Para nosotros es mas facil y entendible trabajar con grados,
    //sin embargo las funciones de java trabajan con radianes
    gradosEntreCadaPunto=360.0/miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas();

    //para hacer el codigo mas corto y entendible crearemos una variables mas
    //donde esten los angulos que necesitamos en radianes
    anguloEntrePuntos=Math.toRadians(gradosEntreCadaPunto);
    anguloInicial=Math.toRadians(anguloActual);
    desplazamiento=anguloEntrePuntos/2;

    radioDelCirculoExterior=miEstrella.getTamanioPixeles()/2;
    radioDelCirculoInterior=radioDelCirculoExterior*miEstrella.getLargoDePuntas();
}

private void calcularCirculos(){
    circuloInteriorX= new double[miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas()];
    circuloInteriorY= new double[miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas()];
    circuloExteriorX= new double[miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas()];
    circuloExteriorY= new double[miEstrella.getCantidadPuntas()];
    int i;
    double anguloDelPunto;
    for(i=0;i<circuloInteriorX.length;i++){
        anguloDelPunto=anguloInicial+i*anguloEntrePuntos;
        circuloInteriorX[i]=(double)posicionActualX+ radioDelCirculoInterior*Math.cos(anguloDelPunto);
        circuloInteriorY[i]=(double)posicionActualY+ radioDelCirculoInterior*Math.sin(anguloDelPunto);
        circuloExteriorX[i]=(double)posicionActualX+ radioDelCirculoExterior*Math.cos(desplazamiento+anguloDelPunto);
        circuloExteriorY[i]=(double)posicionActualY+ radioDelCirculoExterior*Math.sin(desplazamiento+anguloDelPunto);
    }
}

public LinkedList<Polygon> getDibujos() {
    crearDibujo();
    return dibujos;
}

public void rotar(int grados){
    anguloActual+=(double)grados;
    if(anguloActual>360.0)
        anguloActual-=360.0;
    else if(anguloActual<0.0)
        anguloActual+=360.0;
    anguloInicial=Math.toRadians(anguloActual);
    crearDibujo();
}

public void setCantidadPuntas(int cantidadPuntas) {
    miEstrella.setCantidadPuntas(cantidadPuntas);
    inicializarVariables();
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    miEstrella.setColor(color);
}

public void setLargoDePuntas(double largoDePuntas) {
    miEstrella.setLargoDePuntas(largoDePuntas);
    inicializarVariables();
}

public Color getColor(){
    return miEstrella.getColor();
}

public void moverArriba(){posicionActualY-=10;}
public void moverAbajo(){posicionActualY+=10;}
public void moverIzquierda(){posicionActualX-=10;}
public void moverDerecha(){posicionActualX+=10;}

public void setTamanio(int t){
    miEstrella.setTamanioPixeles(t);
    inicializarVariables();
}
}

public class Estrella {

public static final int MINIMO_PUNTAS=3,MAXIMO_PUNTAS=10;

private int tamanioPixeles,cantidadPuntas;
private double largoDePuntas;
private Color color;

public Estrella(int tamanioPixeles, int cantidadPuntas, double largoDePuntas, Color color) {
    this.tamanioPixeles = tamanioPixeles;
    this.cantidadPuntas = cantidadPuntas;
    this.largoDePuntas = largoDePuntas;
    this.color = color;
}

public Estrella() {
}

public void setCantidadPuntas(int cantidadPuntas) {
    this.cantidadPuntas = cantidadPuntas;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void setLargoDePuntas(double largoDePuntas) {
    this.largoDePuntas = largoDePuntas;
}

public void setTamanioPixeles(int tamanioPixeles) {
    this.tamanioPixeles = tamanioPixeles;
}

public int getCantidadPuntas() {
    return cantidadPuntas;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public double getLargoDePuntas() {
    return largoDePuntas;
}

public int getTamanioPixeles() {
    return tamanioPixeles;
}

}

class DoubleJSlider extends JSlider {

final int scale;

public DoubleJSlider(int min, int max, int value, int scale) {
    super(min, max, value);
    this.scale = scale;
}

public double getScaledValue() {
    return ((double)super.getValue()) / this.scale;
}
}
```

Comment: unrelated: a) don't do any manual sizing/locating ever, instead use a suitable LayoutManager b) for custom painting don't override paint, instead override paintComponent c) don't use keyListeners, instead use keyBindings

Comment: Manual sizing/location AKA absolute positioning of components, gives you exact control of components position, added to the lightweight characteristic of the swing components, makes your GUI look exactly the same on all OS. What would be the reasoning behind the statement "dont do any manual sizing/locating" ? what are the benefits of that? what are the cons of absolute positioning? why would you advice against it in an application such as this?

Comment: _makes your GUI look exactly the same on all OS_ that's wrong (think hardware: f.i. dpi, OS/LAF specific fonts, borders, margins ...)

Comment: Ok ill give you that, yet i asked you to give me a proper reasoning behind this "don't do any manual sizing/locating ever", as i am studying in a university im used to disregard statements such as that one if theres no solid arguments to it. Please enlighten me with an explanation of the benefits of a layout manager, the cons of absolute positioning, and why would absolute positioning not advisable for an application like this one

Comment: wow, a university student, how cool - then you are accustomed to doing some research, aren't you :-)

Comment: _makes your GUI look exactly the same on all OS_ hmm, what if my screen is a bit larger/smaller then the one on which you developed the UI and I resize the frame. With your null layout you need to re-layout everything on every resize, while a LayoutManager would take care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem (color change events) has more to do with the fact that you are expected the events to come from the color chooser, despite the fact that you added the listener to the color chooser's selection model.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

    System.out.println("!! Ping !!" + e.getSource());

    if (e.getSource() == ventana.sliderLargoPuntas) {
        dibujo.setLargoDePuntas(ventana.sliderLargoPuntas.getScaledValue());
    } else if (e.getSource() == ventana.sliderTamanioEstrella) {
        dibujo.setTamanio(ventana.sliderTamanioEstrella.getValue());

    } else if (e.getSource() == ventana.spinnerCantidadPuntas) {
        dibujo.setCantidadPuntas((int) ventana.spinnerCantidadPuntas.getValue());

    // >>--- Change this ------------------------------------------------------------<<
    //} else if (e.getSource() == ventana.ccColor) {
    } else if (e.getSource() == ventana.ccColor.getSelectionModel()) {

        System.out.println("!! Pong !!");
        dibujo.setColor(ventana.ccColor.getColor());
    }
    areaDeTrabajo.pintarEstrella(dibujo);
}
```

Your second problem is a common misconception with `KeyListener`s.  You are strongly discouraged from using `KeyListener` (for the very reason you are having) and instead use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  `KeyListener` will only work if the component it is attached to is focusable and currently has focus.  Key bindings can be used to over come this limitation.

In you `AreaDeDibujos` class, you have overriden `paint`, but failed to call `super.paint`.  The `paint` methods are a complex set of routines which you really don't want to break unless you have very good reason to do so.

You should be using `paintComponent` instead (and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`).  If for no other reason other then fact that `paintComponent` is double buffered and `paint` isn't.

This will, also, mean you don't need to use `g.setColor` or `g.clearRect` as the super paint methods will take care of it for you.

Comment: Once again MadProgrammer you've given me a perfect answer, i really apreciate it

Comment: At least I helped some one today :D

Comment: ty :) will prolly see you again in another question next week